# How to display 3 boxes in the same line?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to design a page using CSS and I need to display three boxes in the same line.

I used three div's and have added `float:left` to the first, `margin-left:8cm;` to the center and `float:right` to the right.

The left and center box are perfectly displayed but the right one goes to the next line. I even tried adding `margin-left:16cm;` , it still goes down by a line.

Can someone help?

Comment: can you post html+css code so it be easier for us to try with and understand?

Comment: Do the boxes have a fixed width, equal width?

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `float:left;` on all three elements, and they will line up next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`float:right` floats the block element right of the *next* block element, not the previous one.

If you want to preserve the order of the `<div>` elements in your DOM, you should set both the first and the second as `float:left` and set the left margin of the third one to accomodate for the space taken by the first two.

Alternatively, you can put the `<div>` elements in first, third, second order and keep your current styles.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that does not mess with your markup, and does not require a margin that depends on the other divs' width is to float the first two divs `left`, and float the last `right`. So long as the added widths of the divs fits within the parent element it should display as three columns.

```
<div id="one">One</div> 
<div id="two">Two</div> 
<div id="three">Three</div>

#one, #two, #three { width: 33.3%; }
#one, #two { float: left; }
#three { float: right; clear: none; }
```

The `clear:none` in the third div makes this work in IE 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .outer{
        padding-top: 4%;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .box{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5%;
        background-color: black;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.whateveritiscalled {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

just simply